# How can i get a Message from IBM webshere que and Send it to Rest API

Tags: jmeter

All i installed a Local instance of IBM Websphere MQ and setup a Queue Call QM1. in there i created a queue call connector. I then create a jmeter script to try to connect to the local wmq server queue. I am facing errors in doing so. When i run the code i get 200 bt the message still on the queue and i would like to be able to read the message from the queue and print it out... i tried using this article but not able to get pass my hurdle:
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-tutorial

[image]

[image: queue]

Here is groovy code i am writing to try to go to the server ....it doesn't need to authenticate and then grab the message from the queue. I am not able to do that currently...Any guidance or help here?

[image]

```
enter code here       @Grapes([
@Grab(group='com.ibm.mq', module='com.ibm.mq.allclient', version='9.1.0.0'),
@Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-api', version='1.7.32'),
@Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-simple', version='1.7.32')
 ])

 import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory
 import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory
 import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants
 import javax.jms.Connection
 import javax.jms.Message
 import javax.jms.MessageConsumer
 import javax.jms.Queue
 import javax.jms.Session
 import org.slf4j.Logger
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

 def logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass())

 // Define connection properties
  def hostName = "127.0.0.1"
  def hostPort = 1414
  def channelName = ""
  def queueManagerName = "QM1"
  def queueName = "connector"

  try {
  // Create a JMS factory and connection
  def ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER)
  def cf = ff.createConnectionFactory()

// Set the connection properties
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, hostPort)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channelName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManagerName)

// Create a JMS connection, session, and queue
def conn = cf.createConnection("app", "test")
def sess = conn.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED) // Use a transactional 
 session
def destination = sess.createQueue(queueName)

// Create a message consumer
def consumer = sess.createConsumer(destination)
logger.info("CONSUMER: ${consumer}")

// Start the JMS connection
conn.start()

  // Read a single message
  def message = consumer.receive()
  if (message != null) {
    // Process the message
    logger.info("Received message: ${message.toString()}")
    
    // Acknowledge the message and commit the session
    sess.commit()
} else {
    logger.info("No message found in the queue.")
}

// Close the JMS resources when done
consumer.close()
sess.close()
conn.close()
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use [Grape](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html) for downloading the dependencies, you need to have [com.ibm.mq.allclient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient) in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) prior to starting JMeter.

With regards to your "I am facing errors in doing so" stanza - we cannot provide comprehensive help without seeing the "error" details and your screenshots don't tell the full story.

So far I can only recommend looking at [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file (preferably with [JMeter debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the components you're using), it should contain sufficient information in order to guess the "error" cause.

Comment: Thank you dmitri for all your help....was able to get it resolved with getting messagess from the queue

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, i was able to solve my first problem. and was able to consume my message:

```
 import com.ibm.mq.*

 def strQueueManagerName = "QM2"
 def strChannelName = "CHANNEL1"
 def strQueueName = "QUEUE1"
 def strServerName = "127.0.0.1"
 def intPort = 1414

  MQEnvironment.hostname = strServerName
 MQEnvironment.channel = strChannelName
 MQEnvironment.port = intPort
 MQEnvironment.properties[MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY] = 
   MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES

 try {
 def mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(strQueueManagerName)

   // Define a Queue
    def queue = mqQueueManager.accessQueue(
    strQueueName,
    MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
   )

   def getOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions()
   def retrievedMessage = new MQMessage()

   // Read a message from the queue
   queue.get(retrievedMessage, getOptions)

   // Process the retrieved message
   def messageText = new 
  String(retrievedMessage.readBytes(retrievedMessage.messageLength))
   println("Received message: " + messageText)

   // Mark the message as removed from the queue
   retrievedMessage.messageFlags = MQC.MQMF_NONE
   retrievedMessage.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE
   queue.put(retrievedMessage)

   queue.close()
   mqQueueManager.disconnect()
 } catch (Exception ex) {
  println(ex.message)
}
```